# NUMA on Intel Xeon: Do Memory Regions must have same size?

Tags: intel, numa

I wonder if the NUMA regions for each processor on the Intel Xeon platform must have equal size meaning each CPU must have the same amount of RAM attached and if all memory banks offered must be or should be used.

Comment: I'd assume each CPU has faster access to the locally-attached RAM, regardless of anything else.  There might be other factors that slow things down even more if each socket has a different amount or RAM attached (assuming the system boots in that setup).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that is not mandatory; although you should. 
Breaking such **symmetry** should have negative impact on performance and program design. 
If one memory region has larger size than other region, how would you allocate memory? Perhaps, you fit your allocation size to the smallest one(otherwise you will lose benefit of NUMA system) or, you may manually treat each CPU differently. Not so happy solutions.
Since it is fair to say all NUMA systems are symmetric multiprocessing(SMP) systems, such design is neither efficient nor achieve original motivation to use NUMA.

Regarding memory channels, again, you do not need to use all memory channels. It just hurts its performance. By the way,
whenever you want to use unconventional memory configuration, it is good idea to consult its motherboard manual or its server vendor.